# Setting multiple AWS resources as attributes for flask app object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask, amazon-redshift

I'm working on flask application which has so many AWS services integrated such as **SQS**, **S3**, **Redshift**, **RDS** etc

For working with these resources in the application, what I'm doing is a follows.
When the flask application is created, I'm attaching these resources as attributes as below.

```
def create_app():
    application = Flask(__name__)
    application.s3_service = **S3 resource created using boto3 library**
    application.sqs_queue = **SQS queue resource created using boto3 library**
    application.redshift = **Redshift resource created using boto3 library**
    return application
```

and running the application.

Whenever I want to use these resources in views, I'm just importing the **current_app** from **flask globals** as **app** and then `app.s3_service` and so on and calling the appropriate **boto3** functions of those AWS services.

What I want to know is, Is this better way to do it or is there any other efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good approach,

- as it may be expensive to recreate new service connections on every request
- connecting again in case of connection loss/timeout is handled automatically before executing a API call